# grid view update

Tags: c#

I had grid view which bind sql  data source and added field to update data in grid view but it did not do any update and no error appeared  and I did not know where the error

SQL Stored Procedures:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GetNewswithType]
As
Begin
Select News.Id,News.Type_Id,
News.Header,News.HText,News.DText,News.Active,News.Add_Date,
NewsType.Type_AR,NewsType.Type_EN
From News
Inner Join NewsType On 
NewsType.Id=News.Type_Id
End  

ALTER Proc [dbo].[UpdateNews]
(
@Id Int
,@Header Nvarchar(50)
,@HText Nvarchar(Max)
,@DText  Nvarchar(Max)
,@Type_Id Int
,@Active Bit

)
AS
BEGIN 
Update News Set 

@Header =Header 
,@HText =HText 
,@DText  =DText 
,@Type_Id=Type_Id
,@Active =Active 

WHERE @Id=Id
END
```

ASPX Page:

```
<div class="m10">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SDSNews" ForeColor="Black" 
        GridLines="Vertical" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" 
            onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True" 
            onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Function" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" 
                Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Header" HeaderText="Header" 
                SortExpression="Header" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HText" HeaderText="HomeText" 
                SortExpression="HText" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DText" HeaderText="DetailsText" 
                SortExpression="DText" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_Id" HeaderText="TypeNumber" 
                SortExpression="Type_Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_AR" HeaderText="Type_AR" 
                SortExpression="Type_AR" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_EN" HeaderText="Type_EN" 
                SortExpression="Type_EN" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" 
                SortExpression="Active" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Add_Date" HeaderText="Add_Date" 
                SortExpression="Add_Date" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDSNews" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="Data Source=ELARABY-1EACFA3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ElarabyGroup;Integrated Security=True" 
            ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="GetNewswithType" 
            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="UpdateNews" 
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Id" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Header" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="HText" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="DText" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Type_Id" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Active" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Boolean" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some code to your update procedure to determine if it's being called:

1. Create a table called `Logging` (or any name of your choice) that has a column called `Message` (again, or any name of your choice)
2. Add a line to your `UpdateNews` procedure to `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Logging] (Message) VALUES ('Procedure Called')`. You could log the values of the parameters passed in, if you so wished.

By doing this you can determine if the stored procedure is actually being called or not. The other option is to use [Sql Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) to determine this. If you can determine that it *is* calling the stored procedure, then something is going wrong in there and by logging the parameters you can "hand call" it to find out why.

More likely is that the stored procedure is never being called, how are you telling the grid to persist the changes back out to the database? Looking at [this tutorial](http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/11/a-beginners-guide-to-the-gridview/), I would suggest that your updates are not triggering a "save".

Comment: I did that and the message was ('Procedure Called') but the problem I couldnot know it

Comment: You'll need to tweak the `INSERT INTO` line as I suggested in point 2 so that it stores all the passed parameters into the Logging table. That way you can use the values logged to hand call the procedure and determine what's wrong. In short, if the procedure is definately being called, it's quite likely there's something wrong with your procedure.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that News table had foriegn key (Type_Id) to table NewsType (Id) primary key